# Scene coordinates not showing 0,0 in top right on device

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing my first game in AndEngine. I want to get the exact coordinates of slider bar on scene (which is sprite) for movement of my player.

The problem is, when I test my game on device I get (6,6) coordinates in top left corner,
whereas on emulator I see (0,0) in top left corner. Why am I getting this offset in my device?

This offset consequently affects all my sprite positions.

Answer required on urgent basis

Comment: What andengine branch you are using?

Comment: pls reply as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that some devices cover up some of the screen under the bezel, which is why you see non 0 scene coordinates in the upper left-hand corner on your device. I have experienced the same effect on my device. An alternative is to change your resolution policy to a fixed ratio resolution policy. That way you could create a buffer around the edge of your screen to account for the error.

Comment: Means ill have a constant offset in case of fixed ratio resolution policy . This is what you are saying? And i can easily substract that from my sprite local coordinates.

Comment: From what I remember using the fixed ratio resolution policy resizes the game scene and centers it. This results in a black frame around the game. Any touch coordinates in that region will be less than or greater than your current cameras height and width. Honestly though it should take no longer than 10 minutes for you to try it and see the result for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

in andengine GLES 2.0 coordinate 0,0  is located in bottom left corner not in top corner